# Use greek letters to name list elements in R

Tags: r

Is there any way to name list elements in R using Greek letters? I'm asked to create a list that should look like `list(α = 42)`. 
The actual result of this expression is equivalent to the result of `list(a = 42)`.

I know it is possible to use Greek letters in plots using `expression(symbol("a"))`, but I couldn't find a solution to use Greek letters as names for list elements. Using `as.character("\U03B1")` results in an error, using just `"\U03B1"` leads to an "a". I doubt that it makes sense to use Greek letters anywhere else than plots, but this is homework, so I have to find a way (if there is one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tested this thoroughly, but R seems to take pretty much any symbol as a variable name without any problems and I could not find any specific rule about variable naming aside from this, taken from `?name`

> Names are limited to 10,000 bytes (and were to 256 bytes in versions of R before 2.13.0).

The code you posted works perfectly for me (R 3.0.1 running under Fedora Core 18):

```
> a <- list(α = 42)
> a
$α
[1] 42
```

That said, I would definitely suggest to just spell out the letter as "alpha", as it is more practical to write and maintain.

```
a <- list(alpha = 42)
```

Comment: One strong reason to avoid doing this in practice is that `list(α=42)` is different from `list(⍺=42)`. One is \u03B1 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA and one is \u237A APL FUNCTIONAL SYMBOL ALPHA, but at least in this font they're literally indistinguishable. There are also [many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha#Computer_encodings) very similar ones.

Comment: @Dougal indeed, I agree. Perhaps the OP should point this out to their teacher.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, name the list afterwards using your unicode symbols in the character vector:

```
ll <- as.list( 42 )
names(ll) <- "\u03B1"
ll
#$α
#[1] 42
```

Interesting that you need to do this. Also your list holds the meaning of life.